# Why is the rectangular duct most like a circular duct?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

> Strangely, the duct with zero skewness—the one most like a circular pipe—was not square but rectangular, with a width-to-height ratio of approximately 1.87. https://physics.aps.org/articles/v8/94

Why is this?

> One of the statistical parameters the researchers calculated was the skewness, which is a measure of asymmetry along the upstream/downstream direction. Zero skewness means a symmetric distribution (like a perfect bell curve), whereas negative skewness describes a lopsided distribution with a long tail in the upstream direction. Positive skewness means the long tail is downstream.

Comment: Note that this article is only about 18 months old, and at that time "the researchers [were] unable to provide a simple physical explanation."  I suspect that an explanation for this phenomenon may not yet be known.

Comment: So from the first paragraph, "The researchers are unable to provide a simple physical explanation..." it makes me think we won't get a good/correct answer for it here. If the researchers closest to the work are scratching their heads, I don't expect us to do much better without doing a lot of actual research.

Comment: -1. Not clear. Your question should include sufficient detail for anyone to understand what you are asking. It should not be necessary to consult linked resources, which should be provided only for additional reference.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is still an active area of research by the original authors. That original article only has one citation, and it to a [Science article](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/354/6317/1252) by the original authors in December 2016.

In that, they try to develop a theoretical framework for understanding the effect. They say:

> The physical mechanism responsible for the
>   net loading is a competition between the wall and
>   interior. The shear flow shapes the concentration
>   into a paraboloid, which creates an asymmetry:
>   Away from the centerline, there is solute behind
>   the leading front, providing a diffusive source
>   that feeds the interior distribution and produces
>   a left heavy tail (locally). This effect reverses at
>   the wall. The relative influence of the wall ver-
>   sus the interior sets the net loading, and math-
>   ematical analysis is required to determine the
>   precise balance.

They then follow with an attempt to model the first three moments of the concentration through the channels and come up with an expression for the skewness. The resulting expression, for long-enough times, is independent of the radial/cross-dimensions and only a function of the axial direction. They also define what they call "Golden" crossover aspect ratios, the point at which the wall effects and interior effects swap dominant positions.

So, ultimately, the physical reason behind all of this is conservation of momentum. But they do provide a model for understanding how the duct shape influences the concentration statistics if one is so inclined to need that.